Calling a function using ethers.js Web3Provider giving error
I've made a simple getter function which returns a state variable's numeric value in the smart contract.
The following is the code I've written inside the App function:
function App(){
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [newContract, setContract] = useState("");

  async function connect() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner(0);

      const newContract1 = new ethers.Contract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", abi, signer);
      setContract(newContract1);

    }
  }

  async function getValue() {
    try {
      const value = await newContract.getter();
      const num = value.toNumber();
      setValue(num);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    connect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {value}
      <button onClick={getValue}>Get</button>
    </div>
  );
}

This is the error I'm getting :
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getter()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (index.ts:400:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)

I tried the above code 4 months ago which compiled perfectly on the latest version of ethers at the time(6.8.1 I think) while ran only on 5.7.2, but now it's not running on any of the versions

There could be many reasons for this error make sure you're on correct network where 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 is deployed on. Switch network first in case on wrong network.
You can check by doing
const network = await provider._detectNetwork().catch(error => {
   throw error
});
console.log(network)

Make sure your contract's ABI method should look like this
    [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getter",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

Is this on a testnet? provide more brief about the network or share testnet URL if you've deployed it on one.
and as you're calling a view function there is no need to pass signer just pass provider directly.

I'm using hardhat node and localhost as the network

Then just make sure to run deployment to your local hardhat node before calling contract's method. When we run npx hardhat node command it exposes a JSON RPC to hardhat network. You need to connect that JSON RPC not the metamask's JSON RPC. If you are using 5.7v of ethers.js on frontend then make provider like this const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545") or the Rpc url provided by hardhat node

Check this resource from hardhat - https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#connecting-a-wallet-or-dapp-to-hardhat-network
